# Mounting bracket best practice for cabinet against wall

Tags: mounting, cabinets

I just received a (nearly) floor to ceiling Wayfair cabinet that needs to be mounted to the wall to stay secure so it won't tip over. At this point, I installed a 90 degree metal bracket with 2 screws on the top and bottom of the right side (you can barely see a bit of the bottom bracket on the right side of the first picture a few inches above the baseboard).

The right-side brackets have one screw dead center in the middle of a stud, and the other screw in a 75 lb rated drywall anchor. I do not believe there is a stud at a convenient location on the left between the wall and the cabinet.

I have about 45-50mm of clearance on the left side, and of course I can further secure it by getting a ladder and putting more angle mounting brackets on top. I have a good 12-18" of clearance on the top before hitting the ceiling.

The bottom of the cabinet cannot be perfectly flush with the wall because it has baseboard behind it, but the top is being held flush with the wall by the right-hand mounting brackets.

When I try to wiggle the right side of the cabinet, I get zero movement at all with a good strong tug - it's very secure. When I try to wiggle the left side of the cabinet, it easily flops around. I'm worried too much movement might pull out the screws securing the right-hand brackets to the cabinet.

What type of brackets should I buy and where should I put them?

I do not live in an earthquake prone area, and this just needs to be good enough for a home job, not a commercial building.

[image: cabinet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of the cabinet wherever the closest stud is to the left is probably good and if you have wide stud spacing an anchor on the far left side of the top instead or in addition.  Note that drywall anchors will feel stiff and strong up to the point where they fail.